# error C2065: 'errno' : undeclared identifier in <string> in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, c, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I had a project running in `Visual Studio 2010`. Now I am using `Visual Studio 2012`.
Now I am getting below error while building the project.
I have looked into `Google` and `SO` as well. But no where I got any solution.

```
    c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\string(557): error C2065: 'errno' : undeclared identifier
2>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\string(557): error C2065: 'errno' : undeclared identifier
2>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\string(562): error C2065: 'errno' : undeclared identifier
2>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\string(574): error C2065: 'errno' : undeclared identifier
2>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\string(579): error C2065: 'errno' : undeclared identifier
```

I have tried with including `stdlib.h` into the `sting` header file but still I am getting this same error.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you include `errno.h` in your code?

Comment: looks like you are missing #include<cerrno>, still a bit weird since I would assume std::string would include everything it needs itself.

Comment: How did you switch to VS2012, did you convert the solution and projects oder did you create a new project with the wizard and include the existing source?
Did you completely rebuild after going to VS2012, or is it possible that there still is intermediate output lying around that was built with VS2010?

Comment: @verbose: No I did not use `errno.h`

Comment: Try it including `cerrno` or `errno.h` and tell us what happens.

Comment: @SvenS: I have just doubble clicked on the `VS2010` `solution` and it automatically took its own settings and then I started building the code

Comment: Ah, OK, I'm not actually that familiar with VS2012. Now that you mention it, I heard they can open older Solutions without converting now. Still, I would suggest completely rebuilding if you haven't done that yet, just to be safe.

Comment: line 557 says errno = 0 in the stoi function inside a  #if _HAS_CPP0X block. Have you tried to convert a project and something else has actually gone wrong?

Comment: @verbose in C++ which I'm inferring from the inclusion of string one should really #include<cerrno> and not #include<errno.h>

Answer (score 5):

There could be several possible reasons for this problem.  The
first thing you should do is to create a one line source:

```
#include <string>
```

and *nothing* else, and try to compile it.  If this doesn't
compile, there is a problem with your installation, and you
should reinstall it.  Then, just to be sure, delete *everything*
in your source tree except the actual sources, project files and
solution, and rebuild.  There may be some old files laying
around which are somehow causing the problem.  I doubt it, but
this is something you should do anyway, any time you upgrade
a compiler, or even just install a patch.  (If you've got
everything under source code control, which you should, the
simplest solution is just to delete everything, and do a new,
clean checkout.)

If these measures don't solve the problem (and somehow,
I suspect they won't), there's a problem in your code base
somewhere.  `errno` is required to be a macro by the standard;
to get the error message you cite, the macro must be undefined.
`<string>` includes (indirectly) a file which defines it.  Given
this, the only cause I can think of is that an earlier include
file has already included a file which defines `errno`, and then
`#undef`ed it.  To verify this, put your `#include <string>` as
the very first include of your source, and see if this solves
the problem.  If it does, then you have to find the file which
does the `#undef`, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Strangely enough, the problem was not including "using namespace std;" under the header file includes.  Apparently, program would recognize "string" unless I did this, even though "char", "float", etc were recognized.

Comment: We were missing some preprocessor directive at propoties -> c/c++ -> Preprocessor. When we added those preprocessor then I got rid of these errors